# Scrapy Output File is Blank

Tags: python, scrapy

I created a scrapy spider, but when I run the command

```
scrapy crawl scrapytest -o output.json
```

it runs, but the output report is blank. I know the xpath is correct so I'm not really sure. Still really new to scrapy. Any help is appreciated

```
import scrapy

class TestspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'testspider'
    allowed_domains = ['bing.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.bing.com/']
    url = [
            'https://www.bing.com/search?q=sample+search&FORM=AWRE'
          ]
    def parse(self, response):
        response.xpath('//*[@class="b_algo"]/h2/a/text()').extract()
        yield scrapy.Request(url = url, callback = self.parse)
```

Comment: You can examine your scraped content with the scrapy shell. It seems bing.com is using client-side rendering, in which case you'll need to render the whole content to scrape it with something like Selenium

Answer (score 0):

Bing knows that you aren't using a regular browser therefore do experiment with headers.

Try these settings in settings.py {scrapy only}:

```py
USER_AGENT  = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/532.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) ChromePlus/4.0.222.3 Chrome/4.0.222.3 Safari/532.2'
```

```py
DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'cookie': 'MUID=; SRCHD=AF=NOFORM; SRCHUID=1; SRCHUSR=; _EDGE_S=SID=; MUIDB=; _SS=SID=; ipv6=; SRCHHPGUSR=;',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not yielding any data.

You need to yield dictionaries or instances of a subclass of Scrapy’s `Item` class containing the extracted data for that data to reach the output file.

See the [corresponding section from the Scrapy tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#extracting-data-in-our-spider).